# access output from mongoDB map reduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

How do I access the output from the following mongoDB map reduce code?  I assume that the map reduce function is producing a collection called 'session_stat' with fields: 'dayOfWeek' and 'count' that I can print using find() and my printValue function. But when I execute the code using 'mongo code.js', I just get "undefined".  Thanks in advance.

```
db = db.getSiblingDB("mrex");

// simulate saving records that log the lengths of user sessions in seconds                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
db.session.save({userid:"a", time: ISODate('2011-11-03 14:17:00'), length: 95});
db.session.save({userid:"b", time: ISODate('2011-11-03 14:23:00'), length: 110});
db.session.save({userid:"c", time: ISODate('2011-11-03 15:02:00'), length: 120});
db.session.save({userid:"d", time: ISODate('2011-11-03 16:45:00'), length: 45});

function mapf()
{
    emit(this.time.getDay(),
     {count:1});
}

function reducef(key, values)
{
    var r = {dayOfWeek:key, count:0};
    values.forEach(function(v)
               {
                   r.count += v.count;
               });
    return r;
}

var mrcom1 = db.runCommand( { mapreduce:"session",
                          map:mapf,
                          reduce:reducef,
                          query: {time: {$gt:ISODate('2011-11-03 00:00:00')}},
                          out: { reduce: "session_stat" }
});

function printValue (r) {
    print(r.count)
};

db.session_stat.find().forEach(printValue)
```

Comment: Your code could be a lot simpler - you don't need to emit value as {count:1}, you can just emit 1. Your reduce just needs to have r as 0 and forEach would be r+=v; Session stat will then have key, value pairs with value:<final count> and the print would be (r.value); or printjson(r) if you want to see the whole record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB's map-reduce command generates a set of documents with a field named "value", which contains the reduce return value.  You'll need to reach inside this field to find your subdocument.

Use this instead as your printValue function:

```
function printValue (r) {
    print(r.value.count)
};
```

Comment: You saved me a lot of time - thanks.  How did you know this?  It'd be great if I didn't have to ask these simple questions.  Couldn't find your answer in the manual, either.

Comment: I ran the code snippet you provided and saw the document structure by running `db.session_stat.find()` at the shell.  I haven't looked yet at the documentation, but here's a link to a good example that shows it: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/count_tags/

Comment: That's helpful.  Thanks again.